# PHP to Postgres - Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect()

Tags: php, apache, postgresql

I've just set Postgres up on my Mac (El Capitan) and I am trying to connect to it via PHP... however, when I submit a sample form, I get "Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect()". I've been researching this on Stack (which is how I got this far), but I'm not sure where I need to go from here.

Here's how I've put this together so far...

- I use homebrew, and I ran `brew install php55-pdo-pgsql`.
- I updated my Apache httpd.conf file, replacing `LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` with `LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/opt/php55/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`.
- I restarted Apache.

I'm not sure if it's helpful here or not, but here's the PHP...

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$species = $_POST['species'];

$conn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=menagerie user=root password=****");
pg_query($conn, "INSERT INTO pet (name, species) VALUES ('$name', '$species')");
```

What have I overlooked?  Thanks very much.

Comment: pdo-pgsql !== pgsql. You could try, `$db = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'user', 'pass'); print_r($db->query('select * from pet limit 3)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));`

Comment: try this brew install php5-pgsql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know if this is the best solution, but I updated my PHP to version 5.6 and that took care of it.

Documentation here - http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/upgrade-php-on-osx/

Hope that is helpful.